# Java FileInputStream.read() when printed shows undesired characters

Tags: java, java-io, fileinputstream

The tutorial I'm following showed the following code

```
            System.out.println("File contents: ");
            int character;
            while((character=fileinputstream.read())!=-1) { 
                System.out.print((char)character);
            }
            fileinputstream.close();
```

I tried it the following way

```
            System.out.println("File contents: ");
            while((fileinputstream.read())!=-1) {   
                System.out.print((char)fileinputstream.read());
            }
            fileinputstream.close();
```

Now, I understand that here some bytes are going to get skipped. But the bytes that aren't skipped are expected to be printed as they are. But the output is very different with random characters.

I would like to understand the problem here. Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: 'bytes' and 'characters' are different things.  A character may, for example, be more than one byte.  (And putting a byte into a variable named 'character' does not make it a character).  So by skipping every other byte, you may be skipping a part of a character, and the parts you don't skip may not make sense when considered to be bytes of the same character.  What exactly happens depends on what is in the file/

Comment: @user16632363 Can we say that the ascii codes are read partially and thus form different ascii codes which in turn correspond to other characters?

Comment: We should not bother mentioning ASCII, since this is Java, which does not use that obsolete standard.  Java characters are Unicode characters.  Byte sequences are often the UTF-8 representation of Unicode characters.  UTF-8 has multi-byte characters; ASCII, a 7-bit code, does not.

Comment: But yes, **character** codes are read partially, and thus their constituent bytes are incorrectly recombined to make other characters.

Comment: @user16632363 Thanks for the help! I didn't know much about UTF-8 representation.

Comment: The output is very different from what? What's in the file?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `fileinputstream.read`, it would read the byte of the cursor pointed to and move the cursor to the next byte. Since the `read` method is called when while loop condition is executed and a byte read out is gone. The tutorial used a variable to hold the value of that byte to prevent it is gone.

So just follow the tutorial

Comment: He knew that part: *I understand that here some bytes are going to get skipped.*